# Can't subscribe to ValueObservable after all StreamSubscriptions are closed

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I have a situation where when all the `StreamSubscriptions` listening to a `ValueObservable` are closed, no new `StreamSubscriptions` that subscribe after that receive any data events.

Is this proper behavior? And if so how can I prevent it?

Answer (score -1):

The best way here is used BloC pattern and in the bloc, you can handle the observables and the streams you need to do something like this:

```
    class LoginBloC implements BaseBloC {
  UserRepository _userRepository;

  LoginBloC(this._userRepository);

  BehaviorSubject<Result<String>> _loginController = new BehaviorSubject();

  Stream<Result<String>> get loginResult => _loginController.stream;


  void login(String email, String password) async {
    updateErrorFromResult(null);
    isLoading = true;
    final res = await _userRepository.login(email, password);
    updateErrorFromResult(res);
    sinkAdd(_loginController, res);
    isLoading = false;
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _loginController.close();
  }
}
```

As you can see in this example you create the streams and later you close them on the dispose method

So in your view, you use the strem doing this:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    bloc.loginResult.listen((res) {
      if (res is ResultSuccess<String>) {
        NavigationUtils.pushReplacement(
            context,
            HomePage(
            ));
      }
    });
  }
```

In this case, you execute navigation when the response of the login is success